# Error in date formation Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, utf-8, oracle11g, date-formatting

I have a web application which generates pdf files, and in the code I call such query: `select to_char(sysdate, 'dd.month.yyyy') from dual;` When I execute it in sqldeveloper, it shows me correct data where month in character format(`04.december.2014`). But, when I generate pdf file, it shows me month in digit format(`04.12.2014`).

How it could be? You can clearly can see that, I strongly set the format of the month.

P/s: the code worked well, but we changed the Database encoding to UTF-8. And after that we come up to such error. For generating pdf files, we use xml annotation and rtf template.

in xml annotation I have the following code:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
    <dataTemplate name="DATA" version="1.0">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="OrderID" dataType="number"/>
    </parameters>
    <dataQuery>
        <sqlStatement name="ROW">
            <![CDATA[Select Distinct Order_Id
                ,Order_Number
                ,to_char(sysdate+1, 'DD.MONTH.YYYY') as ORDERDATE
                From Table(Xxtc_Po_Approve_Pkg.Get_Gps_Report(:OrderID))]]>
        </sqlStatement>
    </dataQuery>
    <dataStructure>
        <group name="Q1" source="ROW">
            <element name="ORDER_ID" value="ORDER_ID" />
            <element name="ORDER_NUMBER" value="ORDER_NUMBER" />
        </group>      
    </dataStructure>
</dataTemplate>
```

Comment: does the select statement in CDATA gives the correct result in sqldeveloper

Comment: try create a column with varchar and update the same with above format and use it in select statement and see whether it works.

Comment: @Exhausted, it also shows me in the digit format

Comment: @problem exists with pdf creation, how you are creating the pdf any specific tool

Comment: I think that it depends on system user, and in his `nls_lang` configure. But I don't know how to capture it.